# Error opening project from Source Control

Tags: iis, version-control, projects-and-solutions

I had originally bound a website in my IIS to `D:\Project\ortund\` but later decided to move it to `D:\web\ortund\` for reasons.

I copied the project files to the new location and changed the binding in IIS.
Now whenever I open the solution from my source control (Dynamsoft SourceAnywhere), Visual Studio gives the following error:

[image]

It's very generic so I'm not sure what the problem is here.

Has anyone seen this before or got any clue how to fix it? Restarting Visual Studio as is recommended doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Try use File->Source Control->Change Source Control to update the source control binding info.

To move your project location on your local disk, it's recommended that you use File->Source Control->Open from Source Control and retrieve your project to the new location. This way, the binding info will be updated automatically.

Comment: Hey thanks :) I actually forgot I asked this, so you can imagine what hope I had that it would be answered... Should have bounty'd it and given that to you... Now, would the "move location" suggestion apply for projects to which this has already happened?

Comment: Actually, I'm not able to update the source control on a project where this has happened. The error just keeps popping up when I click on Change Source Control, so I guess I'd have to remove it entirely from my hard drive and open it again in that location from the source control

Comment: You are welcome. :) Yes, please try opening the project from source control in the new folder and see how it works.